# GTK3 File chooser Recent list

Tags: gtk, gtk3, filechooser

I have a GTK+-3 application, which has a File-chooser widget. Everything works, except I can't really find the files I opened in the application earlier in the Recent list. Is there any special call that records the files I opened?

Comment: I'll comment it first, then you tell me if it also works for you. I deleted the file `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`, then opened a file on Firefox, Chrome, Ristretto and the list of recent files was gone. After opening a file, it started populating again with the proper recent files. I run XFCE 4.16 on Debian Testing.

Answer (score 0):

I want is different from yours. I do not want history on my manjaro-KDE. HandBrake(gtk3) choose file got recnet files. I search with bing and got gtk3 del the function to log recent files....But indeed it keep log now. I find the config file(~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini). But the history is not there, it maybe in ~/.local/share/RecentDocuments/. So I del all files in there.